# Multiple auth controller middleware Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying specify which functions are able to each user but the problem is when I pass more than one authenticated user to middleware in my controller.

Here are my controller. I'm trying allow just one method for the users but at that piece of code, the second line don't work out. Just show a response for not authorized (401).

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    $this->middleware('auth:web')->only('listAll');
}
```

Someone have some idea how to solve it ?

I tried use:

```
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:admin')->except('listAll');
    $this->middleware('auth:web')->only('listAll');
}
```

Works but it means that will be allowed for all users...

Comment: If you want different methods on the same controller to have different auth parameters it would probably be better to apply the middleware in the routes rather than the constructor.

Comment: The method that I'm trying to use it will be able for both but not for others and is just one.

Comment: That sentence makes no sense. Also you can provide multiple guards to the auth middleware like `middleare('auth:admin,web')`

Comment: It worked thanks! But still a problem! If I use it, how I will define which functions will be able or blocked ? I think that If I defined like that all the functions will be able for both users...

Comment: Define the middleware in the routes, not your controller. Then you can have fine control over which method requires which guards. IMO it makes more sense to be put there anyway.